# Making a tooltip-like flyout-menu scrollable?

Tags: jquery, scroll, hover, offset, scrolltop

If you have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/MG4hw/2/ there is a red menu button. Hovering over it shows a green flyout menu. The problem is that the flyout menu does not stay aligned with the button when scrolling either the blue taskbar or the pink content (they scroll independently from one another).

(The flyout menu is absolutely positioned because as a relative child element of the blue taskbar it would be hidden by the former's overflow-property.)

I tried .scroll() and .scrollTop() (see code comments) but it didn't work.

At the very least I would like to hide the flyout menu upon scrolling if there's no other possibility.

```
function positioning() {
$('#start').bind({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var startOffset = $(this).offset();

        $('.start_options').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: startOffset.top, //+ $(document).scrollTop(), did not work
            left: startOffset.left - $('.start_options').width()
        });

        $('.start_options').show();
    },

    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.start_options').hide();
    }
});

$('.start_options').bind({
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).hide();
    },
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
};

$(document).ready(positioning); //function call upon loading page
$(window).resize(positioning); //function call upon window resizing
//$(window).scroll(positioning); did not work either
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like so?
http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/MG4hw/4/

here is the stuff i changed:

```
var startOffset = $(this).position();
$('.start_options').css({
  position: 'fixed',
  top: startOffset.top + 8,
  left: $("#some_content").width() - $('.start_options').width()
});
```

plus i included a very bad style of css reset, *, so the elements dont have any default values. its evil, but it works for the example.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

here is another fiddle, that also reacts on scroll. check the functions, jQuery.bind() is depreciated since v1.7 in favor to jQuery.on(). plus i used the "hover" function as well, just to show you another method on how to bind mouse events..
plus i changed the order of the functions, took some out of the on handler and put them into the ready handler..

http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/MG4hw/10/

and why are you using jQuery 1.9.1, when there exitsts 1.11.0 or even 2.1 (2.1. is not compatible with some older versions of ie, i guess..)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that - slightly adjusted for my specific needs: http://jsfiddle.net/MG4hw/7/) - solves (the bigger) half of my problem: keeping the flyout aligned with the button when scrolling the left, pink column. However, when the flyout is visible and I scroll the blue ".taskbar", flyout and button still get misaligned...

Comment: Now that's perfect, thank you so much! I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 for compatibility with some other code snippet of mine. I'm even considering switching back to a version before the removal of the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)-event which I am now forced to replace with quite a lenghty expression. Is there any compelling reason against doing so?

Comment: well, as with software, its better to use actual stuff, than old stuff. consider bugs. in case of jquery some newer plugins may depend on functions, that were introduced with later versions. remember, in my latest edit i used .on(). that was introduced in v1.7 so it wont work in lower versions. what is your code snippet? maybe this is another question for SO? also, there does exist some [jquery.migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) that could come in handy? as far as i know, its for older code to work in newer jQuery versions. but i never used it, so i'm no real help here.

Comment: Dear honk31, if you've got time and inclination may I point you to a related question of mine which so far nobody has been able to resolve? [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741260/how-to-prevent-hide-on-mouseleave-when-hovering-over-child-drop-down-menu)