# How to prevent hide-on-mouseleave when hovering over child drop-down-menu?

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, hide, mouseleave

If in http://jsfiddle.net/MG4hw/12/ you click on the red "start"-button, an iframe-element is displayed. When you hover off the iframe-element it is again hidden. So far that's the desired behaviour.

What's not desired, however, is that the iframe is also hidden whenever I open *any* drop-down-menu inside it and hover over the drop-down in order to select a value. By *any* I mean not just drop-down-menus like select-fields coded by *me*, but also e.g. autocomplete suggestions by the *web browser* pertaining to input-fields.

At least for the first case (the select-field coded by *me*), let's assume the code underlying such a drop-down-menu is as follows (you also find the according birthday-field in the fiddle if you manage to scroll all the way to the right):

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Geburtstag</legend>
        <select name="birthDay" id="birthDay">
           <option value="tag">Day</option>
           <option value="01">01</option>
           <option value="02">02</option>
           <option value="03">03</option>
           <option value="04">04</option>
           <option value="05">05</option>
           ...
        </select>
</fieldset>
```

How can I prevent the iframe from disappearing when hovering over the drop-down-menu?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has somehow to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212309/problem-with-jquery-mouseleave-firing-when-container-has-select-box) problem. dont ask me why, but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/MG4hw/13/) works for me.

```
    $('#iframe_register').on("mouseleave", function (e) {
        if(e.relatedTarget != null) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You're awesome, thanks again! Now that I've got enough reputation I've upvoted _all_ your answers! If you'd like to drop an email (you find my address in my profile) I'd be glad to know who my hero is! :-)

Comment: thx :) but nope, couldnt find your email in your profile. but here is a hint. take the 4 letters of my name. add an @, then put these numbers and add a 'nord'. now all is missing is the dot and the com, and you got me. cheers